# Regex in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I want to replace this:

= Session("Example").ToString

with this:

= Cstr(Session("Example"))

Comment: You need to explain yourself better. Replace in the IDE or in input?

Comment: You need to escape the `(` and `)` characters, as well as the `.`. `= Session\("Example"\)\.ToString`. Are you trying to capture the `Session(...)` portion as a replacement into the `Cstr()` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for

```
= (Session\(".*?"\))\.ToString
```

and replace with

```
= Cstr($1)
```

It captures the `Session(...)` portion, which becomes the `$1` replacement.